# Inserting all dataframe rows from a large dataframe into mongoDB using bulk_write is very slow

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

I am trying to insert a pandas DataFrame that has more than 1.5M row into MongoDB using the following code:(pymongo and pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient, ReplaceOne 

#dataframe is a very large dataframe
#connexion is a mongodb db connexion and collection_name is the collection where I am inserting the df

dataset = dataframe.to_dict('records')

collection = connexion[collection_name]

collection.bulk_write([ReplaceOne(
                                 record,
                                 record,
                                 upsert=True
                                 )
                                for record in dataset
                       ])
```

But this takes a very long time to run I need a solution that will allow me to this with MongoDB but much faster.

Comment: What is "a long time" and what is "much faster"?

Comment: It takes more than 1 and a half hours, I want something that will finish in a matter of minutes @BellyBuster

Comment: When you say "trying to insert" , do you mean insert, or do you mean replace / upsert?

Comment: I mean to replace, but I can settle for an insert if no solution exists

Comment: Performance of upserts will be affected by indexes. What is the make up of your data and do you have indexes on the key fields?

Comment: A document contains about 20 fields, but none of them is indexed, I use upsert just so I don't get duplicates in my dataset no matter how many times I run the code

Comment: OK well that is your performance problem right there. You either need to create an index on the key fields, or come up with a different strategy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205590/discussion-between-esdarii-and-belly-buster).

Answer (score 0):

make a unordered Bulk Write Operation, so the process can run parallel on the server.
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html
Option: ordered=False

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30786282)